# search aspx page data to find out

Tags: c#-2.0

how to search the file and folder seach page

Comment: I get my crystal ball warm and I answer!

Answer (score 3):

To list Files and Folders you can use something called [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)

**EXample**

```
void Page_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:/inetpub/wwwroot/demos");
 FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.aspx");
 foreach(FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
 {
  Response.Write("<br><a href=" + fi.Name + ">" + fi.Name + "</a>");       
 }
}
```

*[example taken from here](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=356)*